# Ng-repeat with a Json file using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have json file called **brands.json**:

```
{
  "brands": {
    "Honda": [
      "Accord",
      "Civic"
    ],
    "Porsche": [
      "Cayenne",
      "Cayman"
    ]
  }
}
```

Im trying to iterate through this list and list the brand(e.g. Honda and Porsche) and render using HTML lists.

```
<li ng-repeat="brands in items">{{brands}}</li>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.items= [];
$http.get('brands.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.items =response.data.brands;
});
```

This code works fine but it displays the arrays inside the brand names e.g. instead if displaying *Honda* it displays *["Accord", "Civic"]*. I want it to display the brand names only.

```
<li>Honda</li>
<li>Porsche</li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in items">{{key}}</li>
```

Quouted from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> (key, value) in expression – where key and value can be any user
>   defined identifiers, and expression is the scope expression giving the
>   collection to enumerate.
>
> For example: (name, age) in {'adam':10, 'amalie':12}.

Comment: do you know how i can get the arrays of the "key" once its clicked? using ng-click for exaple if i click honda console.log Accord, Civic

Comment: @user2681696: you just need to access the `value`. For example: `<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in items" ng-click="show(value)">{{key}}</li>`

Comment: Thanks :) much appreiated