# JSON response via http not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Currently working on Angular. I am trying to get the data from JSON file and I am showing the result in Ul format. When I searched in Stack Overflow, I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324100/ng-repeat-with-a-json-file-using-angularjs). I am trying to do the same but still I am not solving it.

This is what I am trying here in the controller:

```
'use strict';  
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

 app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http){
   $http.get('sample.json').then(function (response){
    $scope.items = response.data.countries;
   });
 });
```

HTML code:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in items" {{key}}>
                
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1rSuK3btRpY41Ls8obb9). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you write `{{ key }}` as attribute inside li tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues,

(i)You do not need to declare the module twice , once in script.js and other one 
in controller.js.

(ii) You were refering to angular 2.0 version ,and coded using angular 1.4 version.

(iii)If you want to show all states from json, it should not have a duplicate key, which you could see from the plunker itself

> {   "countries": {
>       "State": [
>         "TamilNadu"
>       ],
>       "State": [  <-- Error: duplicate key!
>           "Karnataka"
>       ]   } }

Here is the working [`Application`](http://plnkr.co/edit/7eamN3YuVvKznYEQY2Dg?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response I want to show all states is that possible can you please explain

Comment: Yes, its possible for that you should not have duplicates key in your json

Comment: Can you please help me how to create a simple json which countries

Comment: but when i try to validate my json it shows correct json i am getting confused

Comment: Thank you so much  I am getting the values but how to remove curly brackets and square brackets and can you please explain me how you did it

Comment: i have modified json a bit to support your requirement, check the updated application. made it simple now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111354/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-sajeetharan).

Answer (score 1):

One other problem: your JSON is incorrect:

```
{
  "countries": {
    "State": [
      "TamilNadu"
    ],
    "State": [  <-- Error: duplicate key!
        "Karnataka"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is an alternative:

```
{
  "countries": [
    { "USA": [
      {"State": "California"},
      {"State": "Nevada"} ]},
    { "India": [
      {"State": "TamilNadu"},
      {"State": "Karnataka"} ]}
] }
```

Comment: Hi when I try to put your Json I am just getting only dot not the value why